# dynamic url redirection via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dynamic, redirect

I need to redirect this URL using htacess:

From this: http ://example.com/city/Chennai/search/search_display_event_type/category1

To this: http ://example.com/chennai/category1

Is there any way we can write in htacees that will redirect like below url
http ://example.com/(chennai | pune | mumbai)/category1

I know this is pretty hard, but I'm really not sure what type of rule would work for this.
because I dont want to write same lines of code for just city change, so i want something like array match in htaccess.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+/city/(chennai|pune|mumbai)/search/search_display_event_type/(category1)[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Thanks for your reply.
But this code is not working...
Its no redirecting to this: http ://example.com/chennai/category1

Comment: What URL are you seeing in your browser?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 http ://example.com/city/Chennai/search/search_display_event_type/category1 http ://example.com/chennai/category1

this works fine with single redirection. But I have lots of cities and categories for cities so it wont be possible me to write same thing again and again in htacess there are thousands of page that create.

so if I use code given by you it shows - page not found

Note: I am using codeigniter

Comment: Well I didn't suggest you any `Redirect` rule. So take that out and see my updated answer.

Comment: But the code is you have given for only old url. How can we redirect from old to new urls with this code?

Sorry I have no experience with dynamic urls.

Comment: This will redirect `http ://example.com/city/Chennai/search/search_display_event_type/category1 ` to `http ://example.com/chennai/category1`

Comment: I did this

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+/city/(chennai|pune|mumbai)/search/search_display_event_type/(category1)[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [L,R=302]

and it redirect to only home page.
take a look at image http://imgur.com/m9GkNlq

Comment: post your complete .htaccess in the question.

Comment: Here I cant paste all code so here is http://pastebin.com/NpzNuTgv
Note: domain name changed with "domain"

There is multiple cities with same categories. We want to redirect city + category

Comment: Sorry you have huge .htaccess, very difficult for me to debug all of it. This rule independently works fine.

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Thanks for taking time to give me solution I have found few ways to redirection.
However if you shed some lights on this specific query.

Below url I can redirect successfully. but I want some part of the urls in lowercase.

Now I want to redirect
from http:// xyz.com/city/Pune/welcome/venue_display/Abc-Xyz/Locality to http://   www. xyz.com/pune/abc-xyz/locality

I want some part of url in lowercase example: (Abc-Xyz/Locality to abc-xyz/locality)

So is there any rewrite rule or anything that I want to mention in htaccess for this specific?

Comment: To convert to lowercase you need to define a `RewriteMap` in `httpd.conf` or else you have to manage this in PHP code.